# Setting rootView.appProperties doesn't re-render root component

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm not modifying initial props:

```
RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"DcWealth"
                                               initialProperties:nil
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];

self.rootView = rootView;
```

only saving the instance `self.rootView = rootView`

and after some event happens on native side, I want to pass different props:

```
self.rootView.appProperties = @{ ... };
```

but my root view doesn't re-render and get new props. (it does if I manually reload the JS)

[docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/communication-ios.html#properties) say that:

> It is fine to update properties anytime. However, updates have to be performed on the main thread.

I checked and I update properties on main thread.

What could be causing this problem?

Related github issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15938

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to fix this issue, it appears to be a bug.

So I just moved the js code initialization part from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` to the body of the event handler I was waiting for.

So basically, I'm initializing react-native app only after that native event happens. This is a hack rather then a solution, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be a bug from the issue you shared. And the work around you're looking for seems to have been included in the issue as well.

[image]

I assume you tried this approach already? Unfortunately, there may not be a better work around.